# Traefik error while parsing host - host is not defined, (docker swarm)

Tags: docker-swarm, traefik

I have successfully gotten this kind of deployment to work in a previous project but now I am running into an issue that really has me stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Goal:** Deploy traefik to a docker swarm cluster running in AWS, and be able to access the dashboard at traefik.mydomain.com

**Status:**  The traefik service is running on the correct node, but the logs indicate an error and I cannot visit the dashboard.

traefik.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.5

    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        mode: host

      - target: 443
        published: 443
        mode: host

    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.traefik-public.traefik-public-certificates == true

      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
        - traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public
        - traefik.http.middlewares.admin-auth.basicauth.users={{credentials.traefik.username}}:{{credentials.traefik.password}}

        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true

        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.rule=Host({{domains.traefik}})
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.middlewares=https-redirect

        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.rule=Host({{domains.traefik}})
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.entrypoints=https
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls=true

        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.service=api@internal

        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls.certresolver=le

        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.middlewares=admin-auth

        - traefik.http.services.traefik-public.loadbalancer.server.port=8080

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - traefik-public-certificates:/certificates

    command:
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.constraints=Label(`traefik.constraint-label`, `traefik-public`)

      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.swarmmode
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443

      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email={{credentials.traefik.email}}
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/certificates/acme.json
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true
      - --accesslog
      - --log
      - --api=true

    networks:
      - traefik-public

volumes:
  traefik-public-certificates:

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

I am finding the same error when I deploy to a local swarm, use a local vagrant dev cluster, or deploy to a production swarm on AWS.

Traefik knows it is being hit when I visit  `mydomain.com` but not when I try to visit `traefik.mydomain.com` - the logs show the errors, as well as the failed GET requests.

#### Traefik service logs

```sh
ubuntu@ip-fak.e.ip:~$ docker service logs traefik_traefik
traefik_traefik.1.tdpt20ipqnzt@ip-fak.e.ip    | time="2021-10-20T14:28:45Z" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from flags."
traefik_traefik.1.tdpt20ipqnzt@ip-fak.e.ip    | time="2021-10-20T14:29:01Z" level=error msg="error while parsing rule Host(traefik.mydomain.com): traefik.mydomain.com is not defined" entryPointName=http routerName=traefik-public-http@docker
traefik_traefik.1.tdpt20ipqnzt@ip-fak.e.ip    | time="2021-10-20T14:29:01Z" level=error msg="error while parsing rule Host(traefik.mydomain.com): traefik.mydomain.com is not defined" entryPointName=https routerName=traefik-public-https@docker
traefik_traefik.1.tdpt20ipqnzt@ip-fak.e.ip    | time="2021-10-20T14:29:01Z" level=error msg="Error parsing domains in provider ACME: traefik.mydomain.com is not defined" providerName=le.acme routerName=traefik-public-https@docker rule="Host(traefik.mydomain.com)"
traefik_traefik.1.tdpt20ipqnzt@ip-fak.e.ip    | hid.den.ip - - [20/Oct/2021:14:33:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "-" "-" 1 "-" "-" 0ms
traefik_traefik.1.tdpt20ipqnzt@ip-fak.e.ip    | hid.den.ip - - [20/Oct/2021:14:33:55 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "-" "-" 2 "-" "-" 0ms
traefik_traefik.1.tdpt20ipqnzt@ip-fak.e.ip    | hid.den.ip - - [20/Oct/2021:14:33:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "-" "-" 3 "-" "-" 0ms
traefik_traefik.1.tdpt20ipqnzt@ip-fak.e.ip    | hid.den.ip - - [20/Oct/2021:14:34:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 19 "-" "-" 4 "-" "-" 0ms
traefik_traefik.1.tdpt20ipqnzt@ip-fak.e.ip    | hid.den.ip - - [20/Oct/2021:14:34:28 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0" 404 19 "-" "-" 5 "-" "-" 0ms
traefik_traefik.1.tdpt20ipqnzt@ip-fak.e.ip    | hid.den.ip - - [20/Oct/2021:14:39:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "-" "-" 6 "-" "-" 0ms
```

#### For reference, the dig command can find the live server but not the subdomain...

```
❯ dig mydomain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31580
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomain.com.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com.       60  IN  A   <real-but-hidden-ips>
mydomain.com.       60  IN  A   <real-but-hidden-ips>
mydomain.com.       60  IN  A   <real-but-hidden-ips>

;; Query time: 15 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 20 10:11:01 CDT 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 90
```

#### Subdomain dig command

```
❯ dig traefik.mydomain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> traefik.mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 61870
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;traefik.mydomain.com.      IN  A

;; Query time: 35 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 20 10:12:17 CDT 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 50
```

Comment: Shouldn't the domains be strings? 
`- traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.rule=Host("{{domains.traefik}}")`

Comment: Thanks Chris - and good catch, I should have specified this is a jinja template and those env vars are in fact strings.